# how to give appropriate margin in css

Tags: css, autocomplete, textbox

[image]

this is  my text box in which i have populated the city names from database and                         implemented autocomplete feature..now you can see that a constant gap is coming in the left side of autocomplete box..how to remove that gap from cs..pls help

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoComplete1" runat="server"    
 EnableCaching="true"
  BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
   MinimumPrefixLength="2"
  TargetControlID="myTextBox"
   ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
  ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
   CompletionInterval="1000"  
   CompletionSetCount="20"
    CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
  CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
  CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
  DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
  ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
  <Animations>
  <OnShow>
  <Sequence>
   <%-- Make the completion list transparent and then show it --%>
  <OpacityAction Opacity="2" />
   <HideAction Visible="true" />

     <%--Cache the original size of the completion list the first time
     the animation is played and then set it to zero --%>
      <ScriptAction Script="// Cache the size and setup the initial size
                            var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx');
                            if (!behavior._height) {
                                var target = behavior.get_completionList();
                                behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;
                                target.style.height = '0px';
                            }" />
            <%-- Expand from 0px to the appropriate size while fading in --%>
           <Parallel Duration=".4">
             <FadeIn />
        <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValue="0" 
EndValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" />
           </Parallel>
         </Sequence>
          <OnHide>
      <%-- Collapse down to 0px and fade out --%>
              <Parallel Duration=".4">
        <FadeOut />
        <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValueScript=
"$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" EndValue="0" />
         </Parallel>
     </OnHide>
           </Animations>
```

Comment: please post some code

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani:which code??..css or asp?

Comment: html or script that makes this autocomplete

Comment: As you are using "list-style-type" would I be correct in assuming you are building the drop down using a list <Ul><LI>? If so adding margin:0; to your UL should solve this?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani:i have changed the code plss see

Comment: @Jonathan:i have given the code pls check

Comment: @Naveen31 I have provided an answer below. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

may be an issue of white-spaces
in your css, add `white-space: nowrap;` and check if it works

Comment: please show the css of your code which you using for this auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
margin : 0px!important;
```

[How to apply css to Auto complete TextBox in ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890563/how-to-apply-css-to-auto-complete-textbox-in-ajax)

Comment: i am edited my answer try this and look that question

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the [Autocomplete demo](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) it would appear you need to add a style to your page below the existing stylesheet.

CSS

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement,
.autocomplete_completionListElement > li {
    margin:0;
}
```